# Get all sheet names in an Excel file in order

Tags: c#

I am trying to get all sheet names in same order as in Excel file to an array. Currently I reach all sheet individually as below:

```
var pathToExcel = @"C:\Users\Desktop\Everything.xlsx";
var sheetName = "sheet 1";
var destinationPath = @"C:\Users\Desktop\sheet1.json";
var connectionString = String.Format(@"
            Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;
            Data Source={0};
            Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES""
        ", pathToExcel);
```

I am wondering how to get all sheet names in an array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this,

```
OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
conn.Open();
DataTable dt = conn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
String[] sheetNames = new String[dt.Rows.Count];
int i = 0;
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
   sheetNames[i] = row["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
   i++;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to add the Package EPPlus via NuGet and use the following snippet

```
  using (var package = new ExcelPackage("c:\\yourfile.xlsx"))
  {
        return  package.Workbook.Worksheets.Select(x => x.Name);
  }
```